# How to define perm in Apache Ant Task FTP

Tags: ant, ftp, chmod

How to chmod in Apache Ant FTP Task?
I tried perm="755" but it complains that: 'ftp doesn't support the "perm" attribute'

```
<ftp action="chmod"
server="ftp.apache.org"
userid="anonymous"
password="me@myorg.com"
remotedir="some/remote/dir"
perm="755"/>
```

Comment: Ant does the support the [`chmod`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html) attribute, you might want to use it instead of `perm`